# Deleting duplicate records leaving the latest

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

In a table I have 2 columns, IPaddress and date. There are ip address duplicate values. But dates are unique. I need to delete all the duplicate IP's leaving the latest IP

Comment: try to use DISTINCT

Comment: you want to fetch only unique ip addresses or you wanna delete it?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using oracle sql deveoloper

Comment: don't edit answer by comments instead add comments into comment box.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @user7417866 : Hi , Yes I want to delete the duplicate IP's which are old. Leaving the IP with the latest date on the table. 

There are a lot of duplicate IP addresses in the db hence want to clean them

Comment: See my edit, you need to have identity column set.

Comment: How many rows in your table and how many rows (roughly) do you need to delete?

Comment: 110 Rows is the rough estimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows you one method of selecting all but the latest rows for an ip :

```
WITH 
 --this bit of code just creates some data we can play with because I
--don't have your table structure in my database
 ip_data (ip, creation_date)
 AS
 (SELECT '1.2.3.4',sysdate-1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.4',sysdate-2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.4',sysdate-3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.4',sysdate-4 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.4',sysdate-5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.9',sysdate-1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.9',sysdate-2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.9',sysdate-3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.2.3.9',sysdate-4 FROM dual 
  ) 
--this query takes our data with row numbers and excludes any with row number
--1 (that is, the most recent row for each ip)
SELECT
 ip
,creation_date
FROM
  --this query assigns a row number to each row.  The latest row for an ip
  --get row number 1.  Numbering restarts for each ip (PARTITION BY ip)
 (SELECT
   ip  
  ,creation_date
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ip ORDER BY creation_date DESC)    rn
  FROM
   ip_data
)
WHERE rn > 1
;
```

You'll need to rework this for your table structure but hopefully the comments make sense.  Once you understand how it works then you can fit it into something like the following :

```
DELETE FROM <your table>
WHERE (ip, creation_date) IN
 (<select statement similar to the above>)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `DELETE JOIN` if you use `mysql`:

```
delete t1
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2
on t1.ip = t1.ip
and t1.`date` < t2.`date`
```

Comment: he don't have 2 tables.

Comment: @user7417866 this is self join.

Comment: @user7417866, t1 and t2 are so called table aliases, here referencing two instances of the same base table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have null values and have primary key assigned, try this query...

```
  DELETE FROM MyTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, ipaddress, date
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY ipaddress, date
) as KeepRows ON
   MyTable.RowId = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Edit After your requirement...

First you need to have identity set to your table, user this to set identity

```
 ALTER TABLE [tablename] ADD Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

once you have identity set have the following query to delete duplicate IP address..

```
DELETE FROM dbo.DataTime WHERE ColumnID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ColumnID) _
FROM dbo.DataTime group by (ipaddress))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your quick response. There is no Row ID actually.

Its a table with columns  - IP address, Area Code, Date added

I want to delete duplicate IP addresses with only keeping the latest date

Answer (score 0):

### try this

```
delete  
from yourtable  aa
where
ROWID in 
(
Select ROWID
from
 yourtable  bb
where aa.ip = bb.ip
and aa.date > bb.date
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response please explain the aa & bb values in the structure. Thank you

Comment: @Ashfen99 they are just alias

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete all records for which exist a more recent entry (i.e. an entry with with the same IP address and a higher date):

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable newer
  where newer.ipaddress = mytable.ipaddress
    and newer.date > mytable.date
);
```